# I need help finding the derivative function of this function

Tags: derivatives

How can I find the derivative of this function ?
$$f(x)= (4x^2 + 2x +5)^{0.5}$$

Comment: Use the chain rule. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: Also, a special case of the chain rule is the *power rule*.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(4x^2+2x+5)^{0.5} &= 0.5(4x^2+2x+5)^{-0.5}\frac{d}{dx}(4x^2+2x+5) \\
&= 0.5(4x^2+2x+5)^{-0.5}(8x+2) \\
&= \frac{4x+1}{\sqrt{4x^2+2x+5}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

This is a composite function so you have to use the chain rule.

The outer function is $x^{0.5}$ and the inner function is
 $4x^2+2x+5$

The formula is derivative of the outer function evaluated at the inner function multiplied by derivative of the inner function.

Thus your answer is $$ f'(x) = 0.5 (4x^2+2x+5)^{-0.5}(8x+2)$$

You may simplify it to $$ f'(x) =  (4x^2+2x+5)^{-0.5}(4x+1)=\frac {4x+1}{\sqrt {  4x^2+2x+5 }} $$